# Using Goup By in Procedure - SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, group-by, procedure

I have two tables in my database:

```
/* Create class table */
CREATE TABLE Class
(
    CId INT NOT NULL,
    ClassName VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    ClassDescription VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    ClassStatus VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    StartDate DATE NOT NULL,
    EndDate DATE NOT NULL,
    Degree VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    TeacherName VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    ClassTopic VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT CHK_Dates CHECK (EndDate > StartDate),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_Status CHECK (ClassStatus = 'Active' Or ClassStatus = 'NAct' Or ClassStatus = 'Archive'),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_Degree CHECK (Degree = '1st' Or
                                    Degree = '2nd' Or
                                    Degree = '3rd' Or
                                    Degree = '4th' Or
                                    Degree = '5th' Or
                                    Degree = '6th' Or
                                    Degree = '7th' Or
                                    Degree = '8th' Or
                                    Degree = '9th' Or
                                    Degree = '10th' Or
                                    Degree = '11th' Or
                                    Degree = '12th'),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_Topic CHECK (ClassTopic = 'Mth' Or
                                    ClassTopic = 'Ph' Or
                                    ClassTopic = 'Ch' Or
                                    ClassTopic = 'Bio' Or
                                    ClassTopic = 'Fr' Or
                                    ClassTopic = 'En' Or
                                    ClassTopic = 'Arb' Or
                                    ClassTopic = 'Rgs'),
    PRIMARY KEY (CId)
);

/* Create Student table*/
CREATE TABLE Student
(
    _SId INT NOT NULL,
    UserName VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    Bdate DATE NOT NULL,
    SPassword VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    SName VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    SLastName VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    NationalCode VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    StudentClass INT NOT NULL,
    HomePhone VARCHAR (8) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT CHK_Email CHECK (Email like '%_@__%.__%'),
    PRIMARY KEY (_SId),
    FOREIGN KEY (StudentClass) REFERENCES Class (CId) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
ALTER TABLE Student
ADD CONSTRAINT New_CHK_NCode CHECK (NationalCode LIKE '%[0-9]%');

ALTER TABLE Student
ADD CONSTRAINT New_CHK_Phone CHECK (HomePhone LIKE '%[0-9]%');
```

I have inserted the below records in each of them:

```
USE School


/* Inserting data into tables */

INSERT INTO dbo.Class (CId, ClassName, ClassDescription, ClassStatus, StartDate, EndDate, Degree, TeacherName,  ClassTopic)
VALUES (1, 'aaa', NULL, 'Active', '20020907', '20030907', '1st','Eetemadi', 'Mth'),
        (2, 'bbb', NULL, 'Active', '20020907', '20030907', '1st','Rahmani', 'Ph'),
        (3, 'ccc', NULL, 'Active', '20020907', '20030907', '2nd','Entezari', 'Ch'),
        (4, 'ddd', NULL, 'Active', '20020907', '20030907', '2nd','Beytollahi', 'Bio'),
        (5, 'eee', NULL, 'Active', '20020907', '20030907', '3rd','Zahirpour', 'Fr');

INSERT INTO dbo.Student (_SId, UserName, Bdate, SPassword, SName, SLastName, NationalCode, Email, StudentClass, HomePhone)
VALUES (1, 'aaa', '20020807', '1234', 'maryam', 'vahdati', '1234567890', 'mar@gmail.com', 1, '12345678'),
        (2, 'bbb', '20020707', '4321', 'marjan', 'vahdati', '1234578906', 'marj@gmail.com', 1, '12345678'),
        (3, 'ccc', '20020607', '1342', 'masomeh', 'vahdati', '1234567809', 'mas@gmail.com', 2, '12345678'),
        (4, 'ddd', '20020507', '1243', 'mohammad', 'vahdati', '1234568907', 'moh@gmail.com', 2, '12345678'),
        (5, 'eee', '20020407', '1342', 'mahmod', 'vahdati', '1245678903', 'mah@gmail.com', 3, '12345678');
```

Now I have to write a query in a `Procedure` to group classes based on degrees, show the number of students in every grade, and also the total number of classes.
I have written the below query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.FirstReport
AS
BEGIN
    Select Degree, COUNT(Degree) as numberOfClasses, COUNT(StudentClass) as numberOfStudents
    FROM Class C left outer join Student S ON C.CId = S.StudentClass
    GROUP BY Degree

    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'SUM' Degree, COUNT(Degree), COUNT(StudentClass)
    FROM Class C join Student S ON C.CId = S.StudentClass;
END
```

The output is:

```
| Degree| numberOfClasses | numberOfStudents|
|:-----------------------------------------:|
|1st    |           4     |        4        |
|2nd    |           2     |        1        |
|3rd    |           1     |        0        |
|SUM    |           5     |        5        |
```

But the numberOfClasses must be `2` when the `Degree` is `1st`.

I do not know how to make it correct. I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: Perhaps you need a `COUNT (DISTINCT {expression})` for your class count. `4` is correct for the query you have.

Comment: I am just a beginner in this field, and I can not really understand why 4 is created@Larnu

Comment: You have a one to many join . `(1*2) + (1*2) = 4 != 2`

Comment: I have added a `DISTINCT` in the first line of the query in `COUNT(Degree)`, but now it is 1 in every row of `numberOfClasses` @Larnu

Comment: Because you are grouping on `Degree`; of course there is only one *distinct* value per *distinct* value of `Degree`; you should be counting a different column; presumable the class' ID column.

Comment: I have grouped the items based on `CId`, and `Degree`(because it was in `SELECT` list). and also used `DISTINCT` before `Degree`, but now there are two rows with `2nd` degree in the result@Larnu

Comment: Why did you change the `GROUP BY`..? I feel like you don't understand what the clause does here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245490/discussion-between-aylin-naebzadeh-and-larnu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you have a many to one join here, and thus the `COUNT` you get is correct, due said one to many join; you have 2 rows that each join to 2 other rows and `2 * (1 * 2) = 4`.

Instead, use a `DISTINCT` on your first `COUNT` on the ID column. Also, there's no need for a `UNION ALL`; you can use `GROUPING SETS` or `ROLLUP` to get the "grand total" row:

```sql
SELECT ISNULL(C.Degree,'SUM') AS Degree,
       COUNT(DISTINCT C.CId) AS NumberOfClasses,
       COUNT(S.StudentClass) AS NumberOfStudents
FROM dbo.Class C
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Student S ON C.CId = S.StudentClass
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(Degree,());
```

Comment: Funny how many people forget about grouping sets. If `C.Degree` is nullable then better to do `CASE WHEN GROUPING(C.Degree) = 1 THEN 'SUM' ELSE C.Degree END AS Degree`